# Sync directory with git repo on new commit

Tags: linux, git, centos, gitlab, centos7

How can I sync a directory with a git repo? When there are new commits to the repo I want the directory aswell. The process should be fully automated.

The git repo is a laravel installation, we're working on this installation with multiple devs, we would like to see our commits live. So thats why I have this problem.

I want to do this in CentOS 7 and Gitlab as my git host.

Comment: I would suggest a combination of https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md and Jenkins.

Comment: You want to to sync the workspace of all the collaborators ? where do you want to see you commits live?

Comment: I'll make sure it runs, I just want to know how I can make a folder mirrored to a repo.